# Unable to deploy WAR file to Tomcat via Deploment Manager on Jelastic version 5.4

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, war, jelastic

I have an account on a Jelastic provider. Since my provider updated their Jelastic platform to version 5.4, I am having an issue that I had never encountered before.

My deployment process is manual and I have always done it via the Deployment Manager on the Jelastic dashboard. That is, I first upload the WAR file from my local machine and then I attempt to deploy it to the corresponding Java/Tomcat environment.

The UI on version 5.4 has changed significantly. When I try to perform the regular process (using the new Deployment wizard), selecting the target Java/Tomcat environment and setting the deployment context to `ROOT`, the Jelastic dashboard displays the following message:

> Warning: Environment XXXXX does not exist.

Which doesn't make sense as I just selected the environment in the Deployment wizard.

At the same time, the environment list refreshes and the XXXXX environment disappears from the list. After a few moments, the list refreshes and the environment reappears, this time with the message:

> Information: The XXXXX environment has been added to your account.

That also doesn't make sense, as the environment already exists and all I tried to do was to deploy the WAR. In the end, the deployment is not performed, because the version of the WAR file that is deployed on the Tomcat node continues to be the old one, and the application does not restart, which is the expected case after manual deployment.

This particular environment has Java 8 and Tomcat 7.0.73. I tested with another environment in the same Jelastic account, which has different Java and Tomcat versions, and deployment works as expected. Both of these environments are used for internal testing of our webapps, but my concern is that we won't be able to deploy the WAR file to our production environments hosted on the same Jelastic account when the time comes.

I have contacted my Jelastic provider (ServNet) and they are working on this case. However, as this might be a general issue with the Jelastic platform itself, I post this here as well hoping it will reach a broader audience.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you described is a known bug has already been **fixed** in **5.4-8** build. All environments with a **32 character long name** are affected.

Since ServNet is currently 5.4-7, use the following workaround until the platform is updated.

**Workaround**:
Create an environment clone with a name more or less but not equal 32 characters long.

Note: Environment Name doesn't include platform domain, for the environment env-2906550.jl.serv.net.mx the name is "env-2906550" and it is 11 characters long.